# finger print or face scanner in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, sdk, oracleforms, ocx

I tried lot of searching to integrate finger or face scanner machine with oracle forms, we are using oracle forms 10g but someone said it will happen in oracle forms 6i and with `ocx`, the vendor provide `sdk` I install `sdk` and then in forms import OLE Library that comes in program unit now I don't know how to use these packages in forms with `ocx` I just need employee id in my form field, how I can do that. OLE Library gives me these packages which are these

```
zkemkeeper_CONSTANTS*(Package Spec)
zkemkeeper_IZKEM*(Package Spec)
zkemkeeper_IZKEM*(Package Body)
zkemkeeper_ZKEM_EVENTS*(Package Spec)
zkemkeeper_ZKEM_EVENTS*(Package Body)
```

these package named I know these are nothing show anything any package but package have lot of code so if you want to study any package please reply me I will show you all detail I assume that everyone have this kind of package. Please help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX (OCX) controls are not supported in web enabled Forms applications.  All Forms versions 9.0 and newer are web enabled only.  To integrate with hardware on the client tier, you will need a Forms Java Bean. Depending on what exactly you needed to do, it may be possible to WebUtil enable your application in lieu of creating your own bean.

Are you aware that you can ask your Oracle Forms questions directly to Oracle employees and other Forms users?  Check out the Oracle Forms Forum for the latest information about Forms.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/forms

Answer (score 0):

If you share OLE libray files:

```
zkemkeeper_CONSTANTS*(Package Spec)
zkemkeeper_IZKEM*(Package Spec)
zkemkeeper_IZKEM*(Package Body)
zkemkeeper_ZKEM_EVENTS*(Package Spec)
zkemkeeper_ZKEM_EVENTS*(Package Body)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited this to make it resemble an answer, according to [answer]. However, it's still rather unclear and unexplained why this would indeed solve the problem at the top of the page. Could you please [edit] your post to explain why this works? If this was a question addressed to Zedan, please delete this.